# Why IE is trying to download file, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have a simple code for uploading an image file and showing it via hidden iframe and json response from server. Its working fine in chrome and firefox but not sure whats the problem with IE causing the file to download and not showing the image. Its trying to download some 239917890.json file. On saving file I can see contents as

```
{"status":"success","id":2,"path":"enoem/manage_logos/show_logo/2","errorMsg":null}
```

java code

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/manage_logos/upload_logo/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public EnoemLogoJson uploadLogo(@PathVariable Integer Id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
        Model model, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    EnoemLogoJson enoemLogoJson = new EnoemLogoJson();
    EnoemConfiguration enoemConfiguration = enoemConfigurationRepository.findById(Id);        
    if (validateLogo(file)) {
        enoemLogoJson.setErrorMsg("Error");
        return enoemLogoJson;
    }
    LOGGER.info("File name is " + file.getOriginalFilename());
    enoemConfiguration.setLogo(file.getBytes());
    enoemConfigurationRepository.saveAndFlush(enoemConfiguration);
    enoemLogoJson.setStatus("success");
    enoemLogoJson.setId(Id);
    enoemLogoJson.setPath("enoem/manage_logos/show_logo/" + Id);
    return enoemLogoJson;
}
```

html code

```
<form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="enoem/manage_logos/upload_logo/1">
        <div class="row">
            <input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-row">
            <input type="submit" name="action" class="cButton upload-logo-btn" value="Upload">
            <input id="close-upload-popup" type="button" value="Cancel" class="cButton cancel-btn-table">
        </div>
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
    </form>
```

javascript

```
var $form = $('#file_upload_form');
    $form.unbind('submit');
    $form.bind('submit', function(a,b,c){        
        this.target = 'upload_target';
        alert('Firing in all browsers');
        $('#upload_target').load(function(d,e,f){
            alert('When file uploaded');    //Not firing in IE but IE is trying to download some data
            var data = $('#upload_target').contents().find('pre').html();
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(data){
                //Here doing showing information from data object
                //working fine in chrome/firefox but not in IE
            }
        });
    });
```

Problem is on IE9 and IE10. (IE8 not tested)

Answer (score 0):

please refer the json format you return.
http://json.parser.online.fr/

return the json in the format as shown below. 
"{success:" + result + ",message:'" + responseText + "'}

Comment: I am not sure whether I got exactly what u r trying to explain.